# Using Mockito, How do I spy Kotlin class with val interface field declaration?

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin

I was trying to test retrofit's api client class in Kotlin using Mockito in Android, which looks like this:

```
class SomeApiClient : SomeApi {

   private val service: SomeApiService

   constructor(service: SomeApiService) {
     this.service = service
   }
}
```

it implements `SomeApi` interface and contains one retrofit service interface as constructor parameter.

When `spy`ing classes with Mockito, the classes need to have no-arg constructors otherwise your tests will fail with `MockitoException`:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Unable to initialize @Spy annotated field 'SomeClass'.
>   Please ensure that the type 'SomeClass' has a no-arg constructor.

If classes have constructors with all parameters containing default values, then Kotlin generates parameterless constructors for it. However, what if the class receives `interface` as constructor parameter (and has corresponding field with `val` declaration), then how can we apply default value to it or declare empty constructor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When spying classes with Mockito, the classes need to have no-arg constructors

No, that's only if you don't provide the instance yourself. So provide the instance, e.g.

```
@Spy val client = SomeApiClient(Mockito.mock(SomeApiService::class.java))
```